# Для чего существует FORCE_DWORD

Tags: c#, com, pinvoke

Смотря на заголовки `COM`, очень часто замечаю что у большинства `enum` присутствует значение `FORCE_DWORD = 0xffffffff`.

Вопрос, это было сделано для того что бы компилятор понимал что у данного `enum` тип `unsigned int`? Или же все таки это поле где-то в недрах используется?

Один из `enum`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describes the sequence of dashes and gaps in a stroke.
/// </summary>
typedef enum D2D1_DASH_STYLE
{
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_SOLID = 0,
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH = 1,
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DOT = 2,
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH_DOT = 3,
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_DASH_DOT_DOT = 4,
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_CUSTOM = 5,
    D2D1_DASH_STYLE_FORCE_DWORD = 0xffffffff

} D2D1_DASH_STYLE;
```

И при определении такого `enum` в `c#` мне стоит откинуть данное значение и просто указать так? :

```
/// <summary>
///     Describes the sequence of dashes and gaps in a stroke.
/// </summary>
public enum D2D1DashStyle : uint
{
    Solid = 0,
    Dash = 1,
    Dot = 2,
    DashDot = 3,
    DashDotDot = 4,
    Custom = 5
}
```

Comment: А не значение ли это по умолчанию?

Comment: Не думаю, т.к. [`0xffffffff == UInt32.MaxValue`](https://ideone.com/8ERA2k)

Comment: Подозреваю (судя по названию), оно сделано для того, чтобы зафиксировать размер данных констант в памяти двойным словом. чтобы компилятор не вздумал оптимизировать, скажем, до одного байта.

Comment: Если верить ответу: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8115895/1051621, то `FORCE_DWORD` гарантирует, что переменная будет занимать не менее 4-х байт.

Comment: Так обычно обозначают конец (последнюю запись) enum'а

Comment: Cудя по комментариям мы пока гадаем на кофейной гуще :)

Comment: @LLENN, конечно гадаем, надо поискать в коде где этот флаг конкретно используется, и смотреть, чего они от него там хотели в таком виде..

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен в правильности трактовки, но, изыскания показывают следующее:

> Предоставленный префикс должен помочь гарантировать, что параметр anme уникален в своем пространстве имен:
>   https://github.com/loganjones/nTA-Total-Annihilation-Clone/blob/d7d0e4d33f1d452d17cf2fed2b2bcb7f6d7d4d14/nTA/Source/std_Defs.h

```
 #define  FORCE_DWORD ( PREFIX ) PREFIX ## _ FORCE_DWORD = ( 0x7fffffff )
```

> Принудительно привести enum к 32-битному размеру:
>   https://github.com/SpyderTL/OZone/blob/64adf66e90aa27bd8ed0430290bd68ff8f7467d3/OZone/Documentation/DirectX/D3d%20Shader.txt

```
 FORCE_DWORD = 0x7fffffff
```

> Судя по коду, составляет индекс массива, финальную ячейку:
>   https://github.com/cooperyuan/attila/blob/29a0ceab793b566c09cf81af26263e4855842c7a/src/trace/D3DStadistics/D3D9TextureStats.cpp

```
 poolTypeU[FORCE_DWORD] = 0;
```

И судя по поиску, `*FORCE_DWORD` относится к `OpenGL` и `D3D9` API, так что применяется на их усмотрение, и явно не входит не в один стандарт или спецификацию.